# What is the term for a bathroom tile which wraps around a backerboard edge?

Tags: shower, tile

I am tiling my shower, and (unfortunately I think) the hardy backer board is not flush with the regular sheetrock surrounding the tub.  The board is 1/2" thick.

So, I need edge tile which wraps around the corner at a 90deg angle and down for 1/2".  What is the term for this type of tile?

It is not bull-nose tile obviously; I just don't know the term to be able to search or ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [quarter round tiles](http://www.homedepot.com/p/U-S-Ceramic-Tile-Bright-Snow-White-3-4-in-x-6-in-Ceramic-Quarter-Round-Wall-Tile-072-A106-1/202192250)

[image: quarter round tiles]

and [sink rail tiles](http://www.homedepot.com/p/U-S-Ceramic-Tile-Bright-Snow-White-2-in-x-6-in-Ceramic-Sink-Rail-Wall-Tile-U072-AT8262-2/204111223)

[image: sink rail tile]

There is also a [mud cap](http://www.lowes.com/pd/Interceramic-Black-Ceramic-Mud-Cap-Tile-Common-2-in-x-6-in-Actual-2-in-x-5-98-in/50159927) (also called *radius cap*)

[image: mud cap tile]

One of these may work. You can search for *corner tile* to find other examples.

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources
```

Comment: I've also seen the term v-cap used.

Comment: If aesthetics permit, don't forget metal strips that can finish your corners. Google "schluter strip" to see what I mean. (Other manufacturers make the stuff... it's just that Schluter is big where I am.)